# assign object and it's method to prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, javascript-objects, prototypal-inheritance

I want to assign object and it's method to prototype, My normal condition is something like

```
var Page = function (){
    _page = {
        id: 1,
        getValue : function (){

        },

        UI :  {
            display : function (){
                console.log('display layout');
            }
        }
    }
    return _page;
}    

var mypage = new Page()
mypage.UI.display();
```

In my situation, there can be lot instances of **Page** class, so I want to intialize **UI** object with prototype, so **UI** and it's methods can be shared to all the **Page** instances. To achieve this, I can use `__proto__` as following,

```
_page.__proto__.UI =  {
    display : function (){
        console.log('display layout');
    }
}
```

```js
var Page = function (){
    _page = {
        id: 1,
        getValue : function (){
        
        }
        
    }
    
    _page.__proto__.UI =  {
        display : function (){
            console.log('display layout');
        }
    }
    return _page;
}    

var mypage = new Page()
mypage.UI.display();
```

But this `__proto__` is deprecated, so is there any better way that I can achieve this ?

**Or**

There is no need to initialize **UI** with prototype, we can use this as normal regardless of many Pages instances, Does this effect on performance ?

Comment: You're looking for `.prototype`.

Comment: ok, how can I use this in my situation ?

Comment: Don't return from a constructor

Comment: The information you are seeking is readily available on the Internet: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
function Page (){
    this.id = 1;
}    

Page.prototype.getValue = function (){

};

Page.prototype.UI = {
    display : function (){
        console.log('display layout');
    }
};
```

It is important that in the constructor you do not `return`, but instead assign the object's properties to `this`, since that is a true instance of `Page`. That will make it possible to use the `prototype` chain.

Answer (score 0):

You should use another class pattern for this, like this one:

```
var Page = (function(glob) {
  function Page() {
     this.id = 1;
  }

  Page.prototype.method = function() { 
    // ...
  }
  return Page;
}(window))
```

Comment: Why the closure?

Comment: For better property visibility handling, keeping your hole class definition inside one scope of code and injecting of global stuff like window, document and so on. So if you want to inject for example the global scrope on server side you cant use `window` therefore you don't have to change every call to window inside of Page when switching from window as global context to another one.

Comment: But `Page` is not using global variables, nor does it use anything that needs to stay private that would otherwise be exposed.

Comment: Sure Page itself does not, but do we know what other classes he's going to use. This is just one of many patterns for creating classes in javascript. You shouln'd use different patterns in the same project. Therefore you have to choose one that fits you needs. Your pattern would also work, but i personally prefer a little bit more control over visibility and not using global scopes directly.